# Am I being underpaid?

Tags: united-kingdom, adjusted-gross-income

I earn £18000 pro rata for ten weeks.

This full month I have just worked is gross pay of £1384, National Insurance was £85, Tax Code 1066L therefore PAYE = £0

Shouldn't my gross pay be £1500 though, as I see no other contributions on the slip.  (I didn't sign up for pension scheme and I don't pay student loans).

Comment: Welcome to Money.SE. It's a fair question, but ultimately had no relation to taxes. I've just edited title and tags and you have your answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you've been paid for 4 weeks' work, rather than 1 month, based on a 52-week year:

```
£18,000 / 52 weeks per year * 4 weeks = £1384.62
```

Ultimately, however, this is question for your employer's accounts department.

Comment: Thanks it seems so.  I think I'll stay aqway from HR to be honest though.